# How to make multithread socket on different vms

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I want to implement multithreaded-server receives connection from multiple clients on different VMs. 3 VMs are in the same subnet. I would ask how to make it can connect to each other by configuring the network on vms and how to change ip and port in code. Here is the code on server:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 12345
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print " New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):
        filename='mytext.txt'
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                self.sock.send(l)
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print "Waiting for incoming connections..."
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from ', (ip,port)
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Client1:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 12345
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    while True:
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            f.close()
            print 'file close()'
            break
        f.write(data)
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Client2:

```
 import socket

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 12345
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    while True:
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            f.close()
            print 'file close()'
            break
        f.write(data)
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are binding to "localhost" IP address it means that your server starts listening on "loopback" internal virtual networking interface with address 127.0.0.1 which can be accessed from local machine but not from outside.

Your server does not listen on any physical interfaces which look into world so even properly configured clients would not be able to connect to your server from remote nodes.

You can replace "localhost" with "0.0.0.0" - which means "bind to all available interfaces".
This means that you can start your server without knowledge of IP address(es) of your own server.
It will be waiting incoming connections on all physical and virtual interfaces which are configured in your VM.

```
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

But clients need to know IP address of your server to be able to connect to it.

Right now your clients try to connect to theirs own VM by using IP address 127.0.0.1

You need to provide clients with real IP address of your server for them to connect to it.

Lets assume that your server has address 192.168.4.4

Then your client code should look this way:

```
TCP_IP = '192.168.4.4'
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```